# Print report on the local language on BMP printer (other then english)

Tags: c++, printing, qt4, bmp

I am developing my application based on ARM9 processor using Embedded Linux (UBUNTU 12.04) Having QT as development enviornment.

I have an interface of BMP printer on USB.

It already prints the reports in English. I need to print the report in the local language using the same BMP printer.

I want to convert an english character in the Bit Map Image  and then print it on the Printer.

That Bitmap image will represent the english character in other language. QT has ***QImage*** class. But I dont wether it will be useful or not.

Is there any other way to do this ? guide me.

Comment: Your translation procedure sounds a bit strange - to print the English world "hello" in French, you would print "hello"?

Comment: No If I want to print English word "Hello" in French in that case printer will print the "Hello" in french. Means i will first convert the english word "Hello" into the French and then pass it to the printer for printing.

Comment: So you're going to translate English into French by converting character by character? Languages don't work like that.

Comment: Yes I want to do it. I found different way but the only way is to just map the English character into the Local language.It is little bit a inaccurate, tedious and lengthy task.Is there any other way, Lets an example of google translation where google coverts. So is there any library or something to map directly /

Comment: You do not have an **ascii** value of the original text?  You have a bit map of "Hello" and you want a bitmap of "Bonjour"?  Is that your question?  You must OCR the bitmap, if this is the case.  This is a non-workable solution (read CPU intensive and error prone).  It is better to capture the bitmaps and have them translated.  Machine translation is never good as word often have multiple meanings and phrases in one language don't translate; your code will [seem stupid](http://www.boredpanda.com/funny-chinese-translation-fails/).  Hire a professional competent translator to look a the bitmaps.

Comment: If you have a mapping in your code `QString out_of_range[NUM_LANG];`, you may render the `QString` to an off screen QBitmap/[QImage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html) and send this to the printer; the translation of QImage to BMP can be done with `QImage::save()`; there maybe a direct to memory way.  I can give a better answer if this is the case.  I think Qt also supports translations in a better way than `QString`, but the same idea applies.

Comment: Yes i must have the mapping.